# Overriding an account feature for editing email/username

Tags: overrides, override-block, template-override

I found the element that i want to remove here:
vendor/magento/module-customer-custom-attributes/view/frontend/templates/customer/form/edit.phtml

I've created a new edit.phtml file here:

app/design/frontend/Myne/default/Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes/view/frontend/templates/customer/form/edit.phtml

My changes are not showing up when i override but they work when i directly edit the vendor file?

What am i missing?

I'm just attempting to hide the checkbox for change email so they're not able to change email.

After my changes i run upgrade, di:compile and deploy static content as well as clean and flush cache.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, this is just a path issue on how to override `*.phtml` files of modules from within a theme. Your current file:

`app/design/frontend/Myne/default/Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes/view/frontend/templates/customer/form/edit.phtml`

The path should be as follows:

`app/design/frontend/Myne/default/Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes/templates/customer/form/edit.phtml`

The `view/frontend` part of your current path must be omitted for this type of change.

Comment: That's it? So i was super close. For some reason i thought with this particular folder you needed to add more files.

Comment: That's it  @HeadWay :)
You may need to clear cache depending on your current configuration. `setup:di:compile` and `setup:upgrade` shouldn't be necessary here for this type of change. Same with `setup:static-content:deploy`, as `*.phtml` files aren't published to the `pub/static/*` directory, they are read server side. Please do take a moment to mark my answer as accepted should this resolve your issue. P.S: I really enjoy the cat on the head haha